# shared function concern

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using the following `Shared Function` to select a value from DB.My concern is that since shared functions are shared among all objects, can this happen that if two persons executes the function almost at a same time, the data will be over written??

I mean the value returned from the DB will be the result of the last (most recent) execution?

EG:

User 1 executes the function and should get **"abcd"**
User 2 executes the function and should get **"1234"**

User 2 executes the function before User 1 could complete executing the function.

But both the users get **"1234"**

```
Public Shared Function SelectScalar(ByVal _sql As String, ByVal _parameterNames() As String, ByVal _parameterVals() As String) As String
            Dim _returnVal As String
            Dim _connection As SqlConnection = Global.Connection.GetDbConnection()
            Dim _command As New SqlCommand(_sql, _connection)
            Dim _value As String

            Try
                If _parameterNames IsNot Nothing Then
                    For i = 0 To _parameterNames.Length - 1
                        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue(_parameterNames(i), _parameterVals(i))
                    Next
                End If

                _value = CStr(_command.ExecuteScalar)
                _returnVal = _value
            Catch ex As Exception
                _returnVal = Nothing
            Finally
                If _connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    _connection.Close()
                    _connection.Dispose()
                    _command.Dispose()
                End If
            End Try

            Return _returnVal
        End Function
```

Comment: Note that local variables are *not* shared.

Comment: My eyes are sore from all the _ and a type called `Global`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shared Function`s does not share their "internal" state, like `_returnVal`. A separate instance of all local variables are created each time the method is called and each call keeps track of their own set of variables, no cross talking can occur when the variables are declared inside the `Shared Function`.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario (concurrent execution of the data access method), the thing that will determine what the users will see is not the code - it is how the database is configured - what the [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) of the queries is.

I suggest reading [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) on MSDN for the options available in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

That won't be a problem in this case. The `_returnVal` is a local, so each caller will get it's own `_returnVal`. It doesn't matter if they run at the same time or not since they each have their own local.

If you were writing the result to a class field that is shared by callers, then you could have the problem you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Global.Connection.GetDbConnection()` *doesn't* provide the same connection to two concurrent calls, as mentioned by all the other answers, you'll be fine.

If more than one invocation gets the same connection instance, you can have a race condition where the connection is closed on one invocation before the other one has completed.

Comment: And BTW, this being VB, you can use `SelectScalar` instead of `_returnVal`.

Comment: In fact, I should say `Return CStr(_command.ExecuteScalar)` and dropping the `Catch` and final `Return` statements will result in identical results to your current code.